# How to animate display of a drop-down menu?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I need help creating a drop-down menu with a table from the child controller.

Example code:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {


  func displayShowCountries() {

   if let textField = self.activeTextField, let superview = textField.superview {
       let convert = superview.convert(textField.frame, to: self.view)

       let row = viewModel.count - 1
       let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
       guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }
       let cellConvert = tableView.convert(cell.frame, to: self.view)


       addChild(selectCountry)
       view.addSubview(selectCountry.view)
       selectCountry.didMove(toParent: self)

       // start frame
       selectCountry.view.frame = CGRect(x: convert.origin.x, y: convert.maxY, width: convert.width, height: 0)

       let height = (cellConvert.origin.y - convert.origin.y) + 8

       UIView.animate(
          withDuration: 0.3, 
          delay: 0, 
          usingSpringWithDamping: 1, 
          initialSpringVelocity: 1, 
          options: .curveEaseOut, 
          animations: {
               self.selectCountry.view.frame = CGRect(x: convert.origin.x, y: convert.maxY, width: convert.width, height: height)
          },
          completion: nil)
    }

  }
}
```

For SelectCountry()

```
class SelectCountry: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }

}
```

Animation works only for `selectCountry.view` but everything that it is located in of `selectCountry.view` isn't shown with animation.

Comment: How do you build your selectCountry? Do you use autolayout?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "nutria"? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nutria

Comment: Y.Bonafons I don't use autolayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try by adding `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in animations block, like following

```
 UIView.animate(
          withDuration: 0.3, 
          delay: 0, 
          usingSpringWithDamping: 1, 
          initialSpringVelocity: 1, 
          options: .curveEaseOut, 
          animations: {
               self.selectCountry.view.frame = CGRect(x: convert.origin.x, y: convert.maxY, width: convert.width, height: height)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
          },
          completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

animations wont work on the subviews of your selectCountry.view because you only animate the frame of selectCountry.view and since its subviews's frames arent "relative" to its frame they wont animate, that why you should use autoLayout, even programmatically , at least to set the constraints of the subviews relative to the selectCountry.view, that way when its frame changes so will theirs accordingly